# Use Sed to modify a line that has an initial space and contains a comma

Tags: sed

This should be extremely simple, but for the life of me I just can't get gnu-sed to do it this afternoon.

The file in question has lines that look like this:

```
                        PART NUMBER  PART NUMBER     QUANTITY WEIGHT         -999   -4,999  -9,999
w/ UL APPROVAL
                                          MIN-3
```

I need to prepend every line like the "MIN-3" line with a ">" character, and the only thing specifically differentiating those lines from the others are two things:

1. The first character is a space " ".
2. The lines do not contain a comma.

I've tried mostly things like any of the following:

```
/^ +[^,]+$/ s/^/>/

/^ +[\w\-]+$/ s/^/>/

/^ +(\w|\-)+$/ s/^/>/
```

I will admit, I am somewhat new to sed.  :)

Edit: Answers that use perl, or awk could also be appreciated, though my initial target is sed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
sed '/^ [^,]*$/s/^/>/'
```

the output is, only the line with `MIN-3` with leading `>`

sed default uses basic regex. so the `+` should be `\+` in your script. I think that could be the problem killing your time. You could add `-r` however, to let sed use extended-regex.

Comment: Ha! That's exactly what my problem was.  Thx

Answer (score 1):

According to your description this should do:

```
sed 's/^\([ ][^,]*\)$/> \1/' input
```

which matches the complete line if the line starts with a space and then contains anything but a comma until the end.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple answer:

```
sed 's/^ [^,]*$/>&/'
```